# TS/ReactJS: can't change i18n language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, internationalization

I am now using TypeScript on my project and my i18n system was working fine until then. Now I can't toggle my languages with "i18n.changeLanguage([language])" and I don't find where is the problem.

```js
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { Header } from "./Header/Header";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import i18n from "./i18n";

export const App = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const changeLanguage = (lng: string) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header changeLanguage={changeLanguage} /> // the toggle is here and works just fine
      <Center t={t} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

My i18n.ts file looks like this:

```js
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import fr from "./assets/locales/fr/translation.json";
import en from "./assets/locales/en/translation.json";

export const defaultNS = "fr";
export const resources = {
  fr: { fr },
  en: { en },
};

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  lng: "fr",
  fallbackLng: "fr",
  ns: ["fr", "en"],

  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
  defaultNS,
  resources,
});

export default i18n;
```

I don't know if it could be important but I changed my "whitelist:" for "ns:" since it doesn't work with TS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find another way to process, but without the i18n library.

My i18n.ts file:

```
import french from "./assets/locales/fr/translation.json";
import english from "./assets/locales/en/translation.json";

export interface Translations {
  welcome: string;
  lang: string;
  // more variables and types...
}

const fr: Translations = french;
const en: Translations = english;

function getTranslations(language: string): Translations {
  switch (language) {
    case "fr":
      return fr;
    default:
      return en;
  }
}

export default getTranslations;
```

In my App.tsx :

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import getTranslations from "./i18n";

export const App = () => {
  const [translate, setTranslate] = useState(getTranslations("fr"));

  const changeLanguage = (code: string) => {
    setTranslate(getTranslations(code));
  };
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header changeLanguage={changeLanguage} /> // the toggle is here
      <Center t={translate} /> // I can use the translated variables here
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the end, I needed an interface for my JSON files, a switch case to change the languages and a state to update.